# Mysql and Hibernate and Lob columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Does anyone know why I get this exception when I try to persist a string to a Mysql database using Hibernate?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V is abstract
```

The annotation for the column looks like this:

```
@Lob
@Column
private String data;
```

I am using Hibernate version 5.2.11 and mysql-connector-java 5.1.44 which are the latest versions I can find. Most people suggest upgrading components to fix this error. Any other ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle driver, hibernate automatically changes big strings to Clob (if you change data type in DB). But in MySql i see this problem and i remove `Lob` from field and change the length of string to 4k.
Like this

```
@Column(name ="foo" , length = 4000)
```

Because default length is 255. But for bigger (than 4k) strings i need to use Clob and solve it by adding this property :

```
name="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it does not work for me. I need to use a size bigger than 4k and I still get the same error when I use the property you suggested. What I did was that I kept the annotation on the entity and added your property. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: No, nothing else needed. you did right.
Let me check my driver version and compare it to yourself.

Comment: I check something, til i check driver version, please add this property also and check it,
`name=&quot;hibernate.jdbc.batch_size&quot;&gt;0&lt;/property&gt;`

Comment: I check something, til i check driver version, please add this property also and check it, `<name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property‌​> `*

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still get the same error.

Comment: I actually solved it by switching the datatype for my entity to byte[] which is what really needed. I use this field to store a compressed json string. Thank you for your help.